# User control with collection property: object is of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I'm creating a user control that has a collection property.  I've done a lot of research and I think it's, for the most part, correct.  The probem is when I define the collection via markup, I get an error:

> UserControls.BreadcrumbItemCollection
>   must have items of type UserControls.BreadcrumbItem'.'BreadcrumbItem' is of 
>   type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'.

I'm unsure why the TemplateParser thinks that BreadCrumbItem is of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControl.HtmlGenericControl', but what can I do in the user control to remedy this?  If I make a property that is of type BreadCrumbItem (no collection) the TemplateParser works parses the markup an generates a BreadcrumbItem instance just fine, so why not on a collection?

Here is my user control:

```
[PersistChildren(false)]
public partial class Breadcrumb : System.Web.UI.UserControl, INamingContainer
{
    private readonly BreadcrumbItemCollection lstBreadCrumbs_m = new BreadcrumbItemCollection();

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public BreadcrumbItemCollection Items { get; set; }
}


[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
public class BreadcrumbItemCollection : System.Collections.Generic.List<BreadcrumbItem>
{

}


[Serializable]
public class BreadcrumbItem
{
    public BreadcrumbItem()
    {
    }

    public BreadcrumbItem(string sValue)
        : base()
    {
        this.Value = sValue;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// explicit string to BreadcrumbItem operator
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sValue"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static explicit operator BreadcrumbItem(string sValue)
    {
        BreadcrumbItem crumb = new BreadcrumbItem(sValue);  // explicit conversion

        return crumb;
    }
}
```

My markup looks as follows:

```
<%@ Page ...
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/Breadcrumb.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Breadcrumb" %>
...

<uc1:Breadcrumb runat="server" ID="Breadcrumb">
    <Items>
        <BreadcrumbItem Value="test"></BreadcrumbItem>
    </Items>
</uc1:Breadcrumb>
```

Comment: Can you reach a breakpoint in your cast operator? Have you tried `BreadcrumbItem : HtmlGenericControl`.

Comment: @mrtig - no.  The error happens during parsing, well before any of my code actually executes.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab(v=vs.90).aspx

Especially this tag at the top of the page

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Spinner" Src="~/Controls/Spinner.ascx" %>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not my issue.  I have the register instructions on the page as required, and the page recognizes the user control.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're trying to inherit from `System.Web.UI.UserControl` could be causing an issue. Try inheriting from `System.Web.UI.WebControl` instead.